# How to override MUI button, so that the color prop still works

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have tried overridng the MUI Button component and while the changes are all consistent, the color prop now fails to change the color of the Button.

```
    cont theme = useTheme(
      components: {
        MuiButton: {
          variants: [
            {
              props: { variant: "flat" },
              style: {
                borderWidth: 5,
                borderRadius: 5,
                borderStyle: "solid",
                "&:hover": {
                  pointerEvents: "none",
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
)
```

How could I do this so the color prop still changes the backgroundColor ? Currently the color just defaults to transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the section [Creating new component variants](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#creating-new-component-variants), you also need to create another variant for `color = "secondary"`

```js
variants: [
  {
    props: { variant: "flat" },
    style: {
      borderWidth: 5,
      borderRadius: 5,
      borderStyle: "solid"
    }
  },
  {
    props: { variant: "flat", color: "secondary" },
    style: {
      borderColor: "red"
    }
  }
]
```

[image: Edit tender-sun-mqoe7p]